# connecting to laravel database with tableplus

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

am really new to table plus , and i searched and dont know how to connect with my laravel database.

i know it requires ssh and am confused between the host and server address, are they not the same?

i have gone to their docs https://docs.tableplus.com/gui-tools/untitled , not much to help there

here is the error am having[image: table plus error image]

thanks in advance

Comment: To connect to localhost you don't need ssh.

Comment: ssl and ssh is to encrspt connection that go through the internet, but on locqalhost. both are not needed

Comment: @YamenAshraf  so how do i connect?

Comment: @nbk i have tried it without the ssl and ssh , still doesnt connect

Comment: you can try local host and second try the socket, you must have mysql client try it alsio with that. and finally are you sure that the server is running, so check the mysql error log too

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you can access mysql server with this command:
`mysql -u root -p <your-password-or-blank>`

[image: A normal connection without ssh to localhost]